What causes this inconsistency in formatting a question in the exam class
For question one the word "The" incorrectly appear on the line showing points while in the second example it works properly. The only difference in the text is that the sentence in the second starts with two capital letters.
I want the text of the question to appear below the line stating the question number and marks allocated.
The minipages are necessary as normally I add a lot of fill lines for students to write their answers.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,addpoints]{exam} 
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion. (Marks \totalpoints\vspace{1cm})}\hfill\newline\vrule depth 1em width 0pt }
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}        
            \question[3] The use of artificial intelligence 
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \question[3] THe use of artificial intelligence 
        \end{minipage}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}

Here is the output


Can you just place the question body in the minipage? E.g. \question[3]   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}   THe use of artificial intelligence   \end{minipage}?

questions is a list environment (like itemize), using \@totalleftmargin to determie the indentation.  A minipage would interfere with that.  (OTOH, paracol would not.)

The minipages are necessary as normally I add a lot of fill lines for students to write their answers. Are you sure? Section 7 of the exam class manual has many examples of commands provided for this purpose.

Thanks for all of the replies so far.

I can't put the minipage after the question because then you could get pagination between the question number and the detail of the question.
2 I know that you aren't obliged to put a minipage around the fillwithlines, the reason I do this is I don't want pagination between the question and the lines.


Can you make an example where you get a page break between the question and the lines? There might be a way to suppress it.

Sorry, I am not sure how to post code in comments. Here is an example of where I need to include the \question inside the minipge. [link]https://www.overleaf.com/read/vsqrjmwsxcsw#ff74a0 contains an example.
Does anyone have any idea why a line with a single lower cap char to start to the sentence is faulty but a question with two uppercase chars seems to work?

@globalzen Try adding \usepackage[all]{nowidow} to your example on overleaf.
